# How to select five selling product in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

EX: 5.  Write a SELECT statement that uses the view that you created in exercise 4 to get total sales for the five best selling products.

```
SELECT TOP 5 Product_Name, Order_Total
FROM Product_Summary 
ORDER BY Order_Total DESC
```

I am getting this error :

> Error at Command Line : 2 Column : 12
> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
> 00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Please I been trying to solve this but I don't how to fix it.

Comment: Oracle does not support `select top`.

Comment: use `rownum` instead

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ROWNUM` here:

```
SELECT Product_Name, Order_Total
FROM
(
    SELECT p.*
    FROM Product_Summary p
    ORDER BY Order_Total DESC
) t
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fetch first 5 rows with tie` as follows:

```
SELECT p.*
 FROM Product_Summary p
ORDER BY Order_Total DESC NULLS LAST
fetch first 5 rows with tie;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention Oracle database version you use; the final "answer" depends on it because not all versions support all functionalities provided in our answers.

Here's one which works in Oracle 11g and above.

I don't have your table, but - similarly, on Scott's `EMP`. See what 3 analytic functions (as well as `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn) return:

```
SQL> select ename, sal,
  2    rownum row_num,
  3    rnk_1,
  4    rnk_2,
  5    rnk_3
  6  from (select ename,
  7          sal,
  8          row_number() over (order by sal desc) rnk_1,
  9          rank() over (order by sal desc) rnk_2,
 10          dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) rnk_3
 11        from emp
 12        order by sal desc
 13       )
 14  order by sal desc;

ENAME             SAL    ROW_NUM      RNK_1      RNK_2      RNK_3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
KING            10000          1          1          1          1
FORD             3000          2          2          2          2
SCOTT            3000          3          3          2          2
JONES            2975          4          4          4          3
BLAKE            2850          5          5          5          4
CLARK            2450          6          6          6          5
ALLEN            1600          7          7          7          6
TURNER           1500          8          8          8          7
MILLER           1300          9          9          9          8
WARD             1250         10         10         10          9
MARTIN           1250         11         11         10          9
ADAMS            1100         12         12         12         10
JAMES             950         13         13         13         11
SMITH             920         14         14         14         12

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Pay attention to `RNK_3` which takes care about *ties* (two or more employees having the same salary). Once you figure out which version suits your needs best, do it as follows:

```
SQL> select ename,
  2         sal,
  3         rnk_3
  4  from (select ename,
  5          sal,
  6          dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) rnk_3
  7        from emp
  8       )
  9  where rnk_3 <= 5
 10  order by rnk_3;

ENAME             SAL      RNK_3
---------- ---------- ----------
KING            10000          1
SCOTT            3000          2
FORD             3000          2
JONES            2975          3
BLAKE            2850          4
CLARK            2450          5

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

In your case, that would be

```
select product_name,
       order_total,
       rnk
from (select product_name,
             order_total,
             dense_rank() over (order by order_total desc) rnk
      from product_summary
     )
where rnk <= 5
order by order_total desc;
```